# Measure for variability of proportional data

Tags: proportion, variability

I have a list of expected values (E) for the proportions of 20 amino acids in protein sequences.In a particular set of protein sequences these proportions differ from the expected values. In a subset of these sequences they differ again, and have a tenancy to be more extreme. I would like to quantify the amount of the deviation (of amino acid proportions from the expectation) in the protein sequences that is explained by the subset sequences.

My first thought was to calculate the proportion (X) minus the expected value for each amino acid (A) and sum across amino acids, and calculate the ratio of this for the protein set (p) and the subset (s):

$$
\frac{\sum_{A}(X_s - E)}{\sum_{A}(X_p - E)}
$$

I don't have the background to be sure if this is mathematically sensible or not, or how it might relate to traditional measures of variability. If the answer to this was 0.8, would it be correct to state that 80% of the bias in amino acid content in the protein set (relative to the expected proportions) comes from the subset protein sequences?

Of course the above measure doesn't take into account the identity of the amino acids that are biased. For example, it's possible that one amino acid is enriched in the protein set (relative to the expectation), but actually happens to be depleted in the subset. In this case the subset bias would not be an explanation for the bias in the whole protein set. So would it be better to calculate the ratio for each amino acid individually and then take a mean?

$$
\frac{\sum_{A}\frac{(X_s - E)}{(X_p - E)}}{n}
$$

Then could a value of 0.8 be interpreted as the mean amount of bias explained by the subset sequences?

I'm floundering slightly, so any thoughts or ideas would be very welcome!

Comment: As you define deviation, $(X-E)$, positive values and negative values can cancel out in the sum. Is this really what you want? Standard statistical measures of variability and error are transformations of $|X-E|$

Comment: Thanks for this useful point. So I should perhaps use (X - E)^2? and then square-root the whole thing as the last step?